# How to solve the error ' Dimension too large. <recently read> \pgfmath@x' while doing the calculations in the table

Tags: math-operators, pgfmath

Need to do the calculaions in the tables combining two three values, I had given the codes

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{calculus}
\begin{document}
\flushleft
{\color{blue}
\LARGE{Powerloss Table}
}
\begin{table}[!hbt]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{16383}
            % \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{16384} % Error
Fault type & No of Modules Affected & Approx.power loss(W) \\\hline
    Table & 50 &\pgfmathparse{int(round(50*250))}\pgfmathresult \\\hline
Module & 20 &\pgfmathparse{int(round(20*250))}\pgfmathresult \\\hline
String & 57&\pgfmathparse{int(round(57*84))}\pgfmathresult \\\hline
Total approx. power loss (W) &\pgfmathparse{int(round(50*250)+(20*250)+(57*84))}\pgfmathresult \\\hline
Total approx. power loss (KW) &\pgfmathparse{int(round((50*250)+(20*250)+(57*84)/1000))}\pgfmathresult \\\hline
Total approx. power loss (MW) &\pgfmathparse{int(round((50*250)+(20*250)+(57*84)/1000000))}\pgfmathresult \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

....

Getting the errors as

Dimension too large.
 \pgfmath@x

l.23 ...parse{int(round(50*250)+(20*250)+(57*84))}
                                                  \pgfmathresult \\hline
? 
....

Comment: I've removed the `amsmath` tag because that package isn't involved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution can be found in the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/545408) by Schrödinger's cat. My answer provides some explanations about why you get error `Dimension too large`.

- TeX has no built-in floating number representation, and all the dimensions are internally stored in a rather small unit `sp`, where `1pt = 65536sp`. Apart from `pgf` library `fpu` and `xfp` package, LaTeX3 kernel also comes with a `l3fp` module.
  (The LaTeX3 kernel has been packed into the LaTeX2e format since LaTeX2e 2020-02-02.)
- A dimension `\maxdimen`, initialized to `16383.99999pt`, is provided by TeX formats like plainTeX and LaTeX2e to store the largest legal dimension. So the legal dimension range in TeX is `[-\maxdimen, \maxdimen]`. (Note when you use `\the\maxdimen` to output the value, you may get `16383.99998pt` due to rounding off.)
- `\pgfmathparse` uses `pt` as default unit. So `\pgfmathparse{1}` and `\pgfmathparse{1pt}` is the same. This explains why `\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{16384}` and `\pgfmathparseFPU{int(round(50*250)+(20*250)+(57*84))}` (50 * 250 * 2 = 25,000 > 16,384) both raise error.

Comment: I think the answer by Schrödinger's cat is the one should be accepted. My answer only provides some background info.

Answer (score 7):

It is a well known problem that TeX has some maximal dimension. There are various ways to overcome this problem. Here I load the `fpu` library and switch it on locally. There are various alternatives, including of course the nice `xfp` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfmath}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\newcommand\pgfmathparseFPU[1]{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathparse{#1}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}%
\begin{document}
\flushleft
{\color{blue}
\LARGE{Powerloss Table}
}
\begin{table}[!hbt]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{16383}
            % \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{16384} % Error
Fault type & No of Modules Affected & Approx.power loss(W) \\\hline
    Table & 50 &\pgfmathparseFPU{int(round(50*250))}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult \\\hline
Module & 20 &\pgfmathparseFPU{int(round(20*250))}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult \\\hline
String & 57&\pgfmathparseFPU{int(round(57*84))}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult \\\hline
Total approx. power loss (W) & & \pgfmathparseFPU{int(round(50*250)+(20*250)+(57*84))}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult \\\hline
Total approx. power loss (KW) && \pgfmathparseFPU{int(round((50*250)+(20*250)+(57*84)/1000))}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult \\\hline
Total approx. power loss (MW) &&\pgfmathparseFPU{int(round((50*250)+(20*250)+(57*84)/1000000))}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that I added empty columns and also the `geometry` package because the table is a tiny bit too wide. This is all off-topic, though.

**ADDENDUM**: Here is a version with different bracketing, with which I get the numbers from your comments.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfmath}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\newcommand\pgfmathparseFPU[1]{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathparse{#1}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}%
\begin{document}
\flushleft
{\color{blue}
\LARGE{Powerloss Table}
}
\begin{table}[!hbt]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{16383}
            % \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{16384} % Error
Fault type & No of Modules Affected & Approx.power loss(W) \\\hline
    Table & 50 &\pgfmathparseFPU{int(round(50*250))}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult \\\hline
Module & 20 &\pgfmathparseFPU{int(round(20*250))}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult \\\hline
String & 57&\pgfmathparseFPU{int(round(57*84))}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult \\\hline
Total approx. power loss (W) & & \pgfmathparseFPU{int(round(50*250)+(20*250)+(57*84))}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult \\\hline
Total approx. power loss (KW) && \pgfmathparseFPU{((50*250)+(20*250)+(57*84))/1000}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult \\\hline
Total approx. power loss (MW) &&\pgfmathparseFPU{(50*250)+(20*250)+(57*84))/1000000}\pgfmathresult \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that

```
\pgfmathparseFPU{(50*250)+(20*250)+(57*84))/1000000}
```

divides the whole sum while

```
\pgfmathparseFPU{int(round((50*250)+(20*250)+(57*84)/1000000))}
```

divides only the last term (and truncates the result).

Comment: Thank for Your help to get solve this problem, but the last line while I am dividing the whole equation with 1000000 the point values should come to dispaly as the power loss in mw for ex, 0.0228 , but it is coming as 0 for me, can you please help me in this

Comment: @Tamil If you replace `\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult` by just `\pgfmathresult` the result will not be truncated. However, if you use `int` in the expression of course there won't be digits.

Comment: @Tamil Please see my update. I think there is little confusion about how the brackets are to be set.

Comment: Thank you very much , Now got it with the results, thanks for explaining and solving the problem

Comment: @Tamil You're welcome! While I do not understand why my answer got unaccepted I accept your decision.